# pFsense, Unifi AP, HP switch and VLANS

Tags: vlan, wireless, hp-procurve, pfsense

I have a Unifi AP with a single `MYNET` SSID connected to my HP 2520 switch on port 23. I have a pfSense LAN interface connected on port 1. AP clients get DHCP (`192.168.1.0/24`) from pfSense and can access Internet, etc. I have static leases for all my "known" devices but also a DHCP pool so new devices can get on to get configured.

I have OpenVPN (client) configured on pfSense and policy route ports 443, etc over it. Some websites drop VPN traffic though, so thought I'd setup a "vpn bypass" SSID On the AP and give it a completely different subnet. I could tell pfSense to just route the entire network out the WAN interface instead.

I added `vlan 200` on the AP and gave it `NOVPN` for an SSID. On pfSense, I followed some tutorials and setup `vlan 200` on the LAN interface. I have the vlan interface enabled, added the firewall "pass" rule for the it. Then, setup DHCP for a completely different subnet (`192.168.2.0/24`). I don't have static leases configured for it yet, if it matters.

When a client leaves `MYNET` and connects to `NOVPN`, the client doesn't get an IP. tcpdump shows the DHCP request come in from the client, and pfSense replies, but that's all I see going on. On the client, the connection times out/fails. On pfSense, I see a DHCP reply going to the client's static lease for `MYNET`. The reply is originating from `x.x.1.1` (pfSense LAN interface). I was expecting it to come from `x.x.2.1` which is the `vlan 200` address for pfSense.

```
11:44:16.625014 IP 192.168.1.1.67 > 192.168.1.66.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
```

I think this might be happening because I don't have any VLANs on my switch maybe? I tried setting up `vlan 200` on my switch but got lost with tagged/untagged/GVRP, etc. Do I need to *trunk*/*tag* the AP and pfSense ports somehow since they will be carrying multiple VLAN traffic? I tried a few things from [this](https://techhub.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/WB/15-18/5998-8156_wb_2926_atmg/content/ch01s03.html) HP link but couldn't quite figure out what was needed to make this work. Any thoughts?

Current HP ports assignments:

```
===========================- TELNET - MANAGER MODE -============================
               Switch Configuration - VLAN - VLAN Port Assignment

  Port   DEFAULT_VLAN  no_vpn_vlan    |  Port   DEFAULT_VLAN  no_vpn_vlan
  ---- + ------------  ------------   |  ---- + ------------  ------------
  1    | No            Untagged       |  13   | No            Untagged
  2    | No            Untagged       |  14   | No            Untagged
  3    | No            Untagged       |  15   | No            Untagged
  4    | No            Untagged       |  16   | No            Untagged
  5    | No            Untagged       |  17   | No            Untagged
  6    | No            Untagged       |  18   | No            Untagged
  7    | No            Untagged       |  19   | No            Untagged
  8    | No            Untagged       |  20   | No            Untagged
  9    | No            Untagged       |  21   | No            Untagged
  10   | No            Untagged       |  22   | No            Untagged
  11   | No            Untagged       |  23   | No            Untagged
  12   | No            Untagged       |  24   | No            Untagged

 Actions->   Cancel     Edit     Save     Help
```

Port/Trunk settings (all ports are set the same as #1):

```
  Port    Type      Enabled      Mode      Flow Ctrl  Group  Type
  ----  --------- + -------  ------------  ---------  -----  -----
  1     1000T     | Yes      Auto          Disable
  ...
```

UPDATE: adding switch configs below:

**running config**

```
switch-2520G# show run

Running configuration:

; J9299A Configuration Editor; Created on release #J.14.54

hostname "switch-2520G" 
vlan 1 
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN" 
   no untagged 1-24 
   no ip address 
   exit 
vlan 200 
   name "no_vpn_vlan" 
   untagged 1-24 
   ip address 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 
   exit 
auto-tftp 192.168.100.120 "/tftp"
banner motd "HP SWITCH
"
include-credentials
password manager user-name "x..." sha1 "x..."
no telnet-server
ip authorized-managers 192.168.1.220 255.255.255.255 access manager
ip authorized-managers 172.22.200.220 255.255.255.0 access manager
ip authorized-managers 192.168.1.220 255.255.255.255 access manager
ip ssh public-key operator "ssh-rsa ..."
ip ssh public-key operator "ssh-rsa ..."
snmp-server community "x..." operator
snmpv3 engineid "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
aaa authentication ssh login public-key
no tftp server
```

**IP info**

```
switch-2520G# show ip

 Internet (IP) Service


  Default Gateway :                
  Default TTL     : 64   
  Arp Age         : 20  
  Domain Suffix   :                               
  DNS server      :                                         

  VLAN                 | IP Config  IP Address      Subnet Mask     Proxy ARP
  -------------------- + ---------- --------------- --------------- ---------
  DEFAULT_VLAN         | Disabled 
  no_vpn_vlan          | Manual     192.168.1.1      255.255.255.0   No
```

**VLAN info**

```
switch-2520G# show vlan

 Status and Counters - VLAN Information

  Maximum VLANs to support : 256                  
  Primary VLAN : DEFAULT_VLAN
  Management VLAN :             

  VLAN ID Name                 Status       Voice Jumbo
  ------- -------------------- ------------ ----- -----
  1       DEFAULT_VLAN         Port-based   No    No   
  200     no_vpn_vlan          Port-based   No    No
```

**VLAN 1 (DEFAULT_VLAN)**

```
switch-2520G# show vlan 1

 Status and Counters - VLAN Information - VLAN 1

  VLAN ID : 1      
  Name : DEFAULT_VLAN        
  Status : Port-based  Voice : No 
  Jumbo : No 

  Port Information Mode     Unknown VLAN Status    
  ---------------- -------- ------------ ----------
 
  Overridden Port VLAN configuration

  Port Mode        
  ---- ------------
```

**VLAN 200 (no_vpn_vlan)**

```
switch-2520G# show vlan 200

 Status and Counters - VLAN Information - VLAN 200

  VLAN ID : 200    
  Name : no_vpn_vlan         
  Status : Port-based  Voice : No 
  Jumbo : No 

  Port Information Mode     Unknown VLAN Status    
  ---------------- -------- ------------ ----------
  1                Untagged Learn        Up        
  2                Untagged Learn        Down      
  3                Untagged Learn        Down      
  4                Untagged Learn        Down      
  5                Untagged Learn        Down      
  6                Untagged Learn        Down      
  7                Untagged Learn        Down      
  8                Untagged Learn        Down      
  9                Untagged Learn        Down      
  10               Untagged Learn        Down      
  11               Untagged Learn        Up        
  12               Untagged Learn        Down      
  13               Untagged Learn        Up        
  14               Untagged Learn        Down      
  15               Untagged Learn        Down      
  16               Untagged Learn        Up        
  17               Untagged Learn        Down      
  18               Untagged Learn        Down      
  19               Untagged Learn        Down      
  20               Untagged Learn        Down      
  21               Untagged Learn        Up        
  22               Untagged Learn        Down      
  23               Untagged Learn        Up        
  24               Untagged Learn        Down
```

**VLAN port assignment**

```
  Port   DEFAULT_VLAN  no_vpn_vlan    |  Port   DEFAULT_VLAN  no_vpn_vlan
  ---- + ------------  ------------   |  ---- + ------------  ------------
  1    | No            Untagged       |  13   | No            Untagged
  2    | No            Untagged       |  14   | No            Untagged
  3    | No            Untagged       |  15   | No            Untagged
  4    | No            Untagged       |  16   | No            Untagged
  5    | No            Untagged       |  17   | No            Untagged
  6    | No            Untagged       |  18   | No            Untagged
  7    | No            Untagged       |  19   | No            Untagged
  8    | No            Untagged       |  20   | No            Untagged
  9    | No            Untagged       |  21   | No            Untagged
  10   | No            Untagged       |  22   | No            Untagged
  11   | No            Untagged       |  23   | No            Untagged
  12   | No            Untagged       |  24   | No            Untagged
```

**UPDATE-2/SOLUTION (as provided by Zac67):**

*Change IP addresses for both VLANS*:
Switch Configuration - Internet (IP) Service

```
  Default Gateway :                
  Default TTL     : 64   
  Arp Age         : 20  



          VLAN           IP Config     IP Address       Subnet Mask
  -------------------- + ----------  ---------------  ---------------
  DEFAULT_VLAN         | Manual      192.168.1.1      255.255.255.0
  no_vpn_vlan          | Manual      192.168.2.1      255.255.255.0
```

*Correct VLAN tags:*

```
               Switch Configuration - VLAN - VLAN Port Assignment

  Port   DEFAULT_VLAN  no_vpn_vlan    |  Port   DEFAULT_VLAN  no_vpn_vlan
  ---- + ------------  ------------   |  ---- + ------------  ------------
  1    | Untagged      Tagged         |  13   | Untagged      No
  2    | Untagged      No             |  14   | Untagged      No
  3    | Untagged      No             |  15   | Untagged      No
  4    | Untagged      No             |  16   | Untagged      No
  5    | Untagged      No             |  17   | Untagged      No
  6    | Untagged      No             |  18   | Untagged      No
  7    | Untagged      No             |  19   | Untagged      No
  8    | Untagged      No             |  20   | Untagged      No
  9    | Untagged      No             |  21   | Untagged      No
  10   | Untagged      No             |  22   | Untagged      No
  11   | Untagged      No             |  23   | Untagged      Tagged
  12   | Untagged      No             |  24   | Untagged      No
```

*Add pfSense NAT rule for `no_vpn_vlan`:*
[image]

Comment: Is `192./162/.1.66` above a typo or deliberate? Note that 192.162.0.0/22 is a Russian network and *not* private.

Comment: Yes, you need to tag VLANs across all trunks that you require, on both sides. You'll need to tell us more about the VLAN and trunk settings. Please add the complete (sanitized) configs to your question as text, using the { } function.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into your question using the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`).

Comment: @Zac67 - yes, typo. Fixed.

Comment: @RonMaupin - Ok, pic removed.

Comment: @Zac67 - added the Port/Trunk settings page from the switch.  Sorry, do you mean complete config of the switch, or configs on Unifi and pfSense as well? Those seem pretty basic as far as not having tagged/untagged etc.

Comment: Yes, all those. If you haven't configure the VLANs on all participating devices that is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the tagged VLANs on the switch as well. By default, it's got a single, untagged VLANs, so all connected device are in the same L2 segment. Also by default, frames with unknown VLAN tags are simply dropped, so there's no connectivity across the switch.

Using a single connection for multiple VLANs requires a *VLAN trunk*. On the trunk you can leave a single VLAN untagged, all others must be tagged. It makes sense to use the same logic on all trunks, or to generally tag all VLANs on all trunks.

VLAN tags are required to provide a VLAN association for frames across links or between devices.

You seem to have created VLANs on the pfSense router and on the WAP already. Make sure you know which VLANs are tagged and which one isn't on the links.

On the 2520 switch, make sure the exact same VLANs are present and that they are tagged or untagged in the exact same way as on the connected devices, e.g. for tagged VLAN 20 on ports 1 and 23 and VLAN 1 untagged on all ports:

```
conf
vlan 1 untagged 1-24
vlan 20 name no_vpn_vlan
vlan 20 tagged 1,23
write memory
```

You don't need GVRP. It's only required in a larger network where you'd want switches to automatically learn which VLANs are used on a link. You need to use/configure GVRP very carefully to avoid security issues - so for a small network, leave it out.

### Edit after `show run` addition

```
vlan 200 
   name "no_vpn_vlan" 
   untagged 1-24
```

This puts all switch ports into VLAN 200, untagged - including the pfSense and the WAP. The frames tagged as VLAN 200 entering from those ports make it into the VLAN, *but the frames from the switch go out untagged*, so they are associated with the untagged VLAN on the pfSense & WAP. If you use my config snippet above, you put all ports untagged in the default VLAN 1 and enable VLAN 200 with tagged frames across ports 1 and 23 - which is more likely what you want.

Don't forget to move your management address back to VLAN 1 as well. Without a serial console that can be tricky since you'd need to remove the IP address from VLAN 200 first, immediately killing the management session. I'd use a temporary VLAN and IP address on an otherwise unused port. But it might be simpler to connect the serial cable. ;-)

Remember that VLANs are essentially virtual switches and tagging frames enables virtual subinterfaces connected to those ports to use the tagged VLANs.

Comment: pfSense and WAP are both configured with VLAN "200" so I think that is OK. pfSense LAN is plugged into port 1. If I set Port 1 to "Tagged" on *no_vpn_vlan* I can no longer ping pfSense from switch or a computer. Can DEFAULT_VLAN no longer talk on port 1 if it is "Tagged"? I thought "Tagged" and "Trunk" can carry all VLAN traffic but maybe DEFAULT_VLAN has no tag?

Comment: You do need to configure a tagged VLAN 200 on the 2520's ports to the pfSense & WAP as well, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I must be missing something. I am marking this as answered however because it has got be a basic task for an experienced network admin. It's clear I need VLANs on the switch and that was my main question. Also good to know I don't need GVRP. I'll have to dig into it more with the info you've given.

Comment: I have added a possible switch config to the answer. Basically, that's why I was asking for the configs - it isn't easy to point at the problem when you don't know what''s configured.

Comment: Thanks for that. If you're still up for it, I've sat down a couple times to sanitize `show run` from the switch and keep getting interrupted. It might be a bit to get to that.

Comment: @Nstevens You only need to sanitize public IP addresses, sensitive user names and of course, security items like passwords and keys.

Comment: I've added the configs to my question. One thing that looks odd is under **IP Info**,  the IP `192.168.1.10` used to be on the DEFAULT_VLAN. Since adding VLAN 200, it seems to have moved. I did not do this intentionally so not sure why it is like that. That suggests to me that all my current network traffic is using `no_vpn_vlan` when I intended to keep that traffic on `DEFAULT_VLAN`. I tried moving the IP back to default this morning but was not on the console so things got messy. By the time I got i straightened out the house was waking up and ran out of time.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you've mixed up. See my edit above, I hope it clears up now. Moving the management address without the serial console is tricky. I'm adding that as well.

Comment: Good to know. I will have to try this tomorrow morning when nobody is using the network. I appreciate the time you have spent on this. Thank you!

Comment: Zac67 - Thank you! It is working as intended now. If you have a Paypal address, PM me (is that possible here?). I would gladly fund a couple pints of your favorite beverage for the help :)  For anyone else running across this, I had to add a pfSense rule (Firewall > NAT > Outbound) for the `no_vpn_vlan` subnet which I don't recall from the documentation I was following. If you don't do this, pfSense sends the RFC1918 address out the WAN interface and the traffic goes nowhere (as it should).

Comment: Impressive teamwork! This has given me a great lead on a project I'm starting separating IP Cams from an office network.